# Websites architecture are designed like static content is served by web server(xampp) and dynamic content is served by Application servers

Tags: architecture, jboss, xampp, ibm-mq

Many websites have architecture like:-

1. Static content served by Web Server.
2. Dynamic content served by Application Server.

When Application server alone can server both static as well as dynamic content,
Why two servers are needed ?

Please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Web servers can perform more services than serving content. They can intercept the requests from the browser and responses from a multitude of application servers.

Here is what I can see as scenarios where web server vs no web server can be identified.

Web Server required when:

- Enterprise have more than one application serving users.
- Access control for the user is needed for several applications.
- Software load balancing for scaling is required.
- Applications serving users need to be fault tolerant.
- Security wise to hide the servers that user is accessing and hence the reduce the risk of threats.
- Static content is served to the users.
- Usability wise to avoid redirections to several applications that have inconsistent look and feel.

A classic scenario is where external users interact with a enterprise and the enterprise uses several internal and external applications to serve the user.

No web server is required when:

- A single application serves users in a enterprise.
- Access control is managed within the application.
- The application has its own mechanism for scaling and fault tolerance.

Eg: Intranet portals serving users by processing simple interactions of users.

Comment: Another interesting aspect on IO is available @ http://www.webforefront.com/performance/webservers_statictier.html

Answer (score 0):

Because for high volume applications you want your static resources to load *fast*.  If your application server is handling services and static content, it is going to be slower.  For truly high volume scenario, you application server needs to be dedicated to running the application services.

Plus, since static resources can usually be cached somewhere, it probably makes it easier to configure the application network when machines serve dedicated purposes.

Comment: Caching point is understandable , but can you please throw some more light on the first point

Comment: what do you mean? If one computer is serving both static content and running as an application server, its not going to respond as quickly as if it were doing one or the other...

Comment: does web server serves as load balancer also ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Static content served by Web Server.

This is to increase speed and save resources like network bandwidth etc. Usually, you have a cluster of servers where the incoming requests are routed to for load balancing. But if it is a static content, that can be served immeditately from a webserver which is acting as a cache/load blanacer without need for computing resources on the actual server.

> 2.Dynamic content served by Application Server.

As stated in point 1. An application server usually performs computational and transactional activities and hence. It is not uncommon for a webserver/load balancer to server static content and route the requests to other webservers for actual request processing. Just to highlight that it is not only a case for the application server.